# define multiple variables in select query in oracle

Tags: oracle, variables, dynamic

Getting error.. unable to define 2 parameters in one query

```
  define price = 99.969000
  define isin = '9128283C2';
    WITH A AS
      (select BUY_SELL,CASE WHEN BUY_SELL = 0 THEN (&price - 0.0025)  ELSE (&price + 0.0025) END BS,PRODUCT_ISIN,QUANTITY
   from table1 t where t.t_dt = '01-nov-17'
 AND BUY_SELL = 0
AND quantity = 25 and product_isin = &isin)
SELECT * FROM A where row_num = 1;
```

Comment: getting error.. unable to define 2 parameters in one query

Comment: Where are you running this? Oracle variables should be defined using Declare varName type := value;

Comment: Could you provide your table details and some sample data?

Comment: *"unable to define 2 parameters in one query"* is not an Oracle error message.